# Documentation of XPath Elements for NReco Videoinfo

Tags: xpath, nreco

I wanna use NReco Videoinfo to access all information of a media file. You get a special attribute by calling a function GetAttrValue(xpath).
It wants a xpath for example "streams\audio\channels" (this is not the correct one I know) - but I don't find any documentation about all available attributes and their corresponding xpaths.

Does anyone can help?

Thanks a lot,
Ewald.

Answer (score 0):

NReco.VideoInfo is a wrapper for 'ffprobe' command line utility (part of ffmpeg distribution) and as result you get everything that is returned by it with `-print_format xml` option.

You also can access this raw XML with `MediaInfo.Result` property which returns `XPathDocument` instance:

```
var ffProbe = new NReco.VideoInfo.FFProbe();
var videoInfo = ffProbe.GetMediaInfo(pathToVideoFile);
var rawXml = videoInfo.Result.CreateNavigator().OuterXml;
```